# Is there memory leak if function returns std::vector<std::string>?

Tags: c++, string, memory, vector, swap

According to the reference:
1. std::vector::swap exchanges contents; 
2. copying strings is deep.
But how about swapping a function returned array of strings?

My guess is, the function returns a copy of the internal strings.  So the swapping should be fine.  However, debugging in visual studio, the internal strings and the outside strings (after swapping) have the same memory addresses at the raw_view, so i doubt my guess.

Thank you.

```
std::vector<std::string> get_name_list()
{
    std::string name1 = "foo";
    std::string name2 = "bar";

    std::vector<std::string> names;
    names.push_back(name1);
    names.push_back(name2);
    return names;
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    list.swap(get_name_list());    // deep copy strings? or access local memory?
}
```

Comment: An example that compiles would be nice.

Comment: both `std::vector` and `std::string` manager their own memory. there's no opportunity for leaking here.

Comment: That swap doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Stop using `void main()`. It's not correct, even though Visual Studio might accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general passing and returning by value avoids memory leaks, though of course the types involved might still have buggy memory management. This shouldn't be the case for standard library containers and `std::string`.

There is no memory leak in your code [edit: assuming it compiles, that is; you can make it compile by changing it to `get_name_list().swap(list)`.] Swapping two vectors does not copy or move the vectors' elements. You can imagine that the two vectors' pointers to their internal data arrays are simply swapped, leaving the objects themselves in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile since you're trying to bind a temporary to a l-value reference

```
template <class T> void swap (T& a, T& b)
```

MSVC seems to accept it and swaps the contents (it doesn't copy the contents) but this is not conformant. It shouldn't leak (it's swapping the internal contents, not copying the contents) but it shouldn't work that way either.

Assuming both a C++11-conformant compiler and standard library in your case you'd better off relying on the compiler doing the right choice: i.e. returning that `std::vector<std::string>` is indeed a temporary and subject to **move semantics**. No memory leak would be involved since you're using a vector which (assuming no bugs in the implementation of course) provides move operators/constructors.

```
std::vector<std::string> list;
list = get_name_list();
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/Csx26i)</kbd>

The signature

```
void main()
```

is also wrong even though, as Brian commented, MSVC might accept it. The standard signature is

```
int main()
```